# Testing jQuery Drag & Drop and Droppable with Selenium

Tags: jquery, testing, selenium, drag-and-drop, selenium-ide

I have a page that makes use of jQuery Drag & Drop, and I would like to build a relatively robust test suite for this process using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org).

Looking into Selenium, I've found that it has a *Drag & Drop* command on a jQuery plugin like: [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), but when I use the Selenium IDE to try to record 'dragging and dropping I don't get any recorded events.

So should I try to target the events using jQuery selectors?

Because the following don't work (targeting the '12p Lunch' on the [example page](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/))

```
<tr>
    <td>dragAndDrop</td>
    <td>/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div</td>
    <td>+100,+100</td>
</tr>
```

or even clicking on the element

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div</td>
    <td>+100,+100</td>
</tr>
```

In both cases the *XPath* isn't found. So how can I target this changing element? If I had a *unique id* in the selector could I target that? Either way the drag&drop doesn't seem to be working:

```
<tr>
    <td>dragAndDrop</td>
    <td>id=targetelement</td>
    <td>+100,+100</td>
</tr>
```

Also can I target elements in the 'Location' with jQuery?

```
<tr>
    <td>dragAndDrop</td>
    <td>selenium.getuserwindow.browserbot.jQuery('#targetelement')</td>
    <td>+100,0</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me...

```
<!--test sorting-->
<!--move block 2 to col 1-->
<tr>
    <td>mouseDownAt</td>
    <td>//div[@id="block-set-col-1"]/ul/li</td>
    <td>80,20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>mouseMoveAt</td>
    <td>//div[@id="block-set-col-0"]/ul</td>
    <td>50,10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>mouseOver</td>
    <td>//div[@id="block-set-col-0"]/ul</td>
    <td>50,10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>mouseUpAt</td>
    <td>//div[@id="block-set-col-0"]/ul</td>
    <td>50,10</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: are you working with the example page that I referenced? I can't find the id's you referenced - are you adding them to the page?

Comment: No this is a test that worked for me in a different project, it demonstrates the process